# mysql table structure for tynemce

Tags: mysql, create-table, sql-types

I'm trying to create table in mysql that will hold a big amount of data with utf8 encoding.

I've read that difference between **LONGBLOB** AND **LONGTEXT** types is that blob stores information about video, music and other objects (about binary data), when text stores information about characters, but I can't create table which will hold such a information.

When I'm creating table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE b( id int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, b_title
VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL, b_data LONGTEXT);
```

it does not support utf8 encoding and when trying to create table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE b(
id int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
b_title VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
b_data CHARSET utf8 LONGTEXT);
```

it gets me error in mysql.

Please advice how to structure mysql table which will store a big amount of data, I want it because trying to insert data from **tynemce**

**PS. I want to store any information in mysql table which will pass through the tynemce**.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/create-table.html), the correct syntax for specifying a column of `LONGTEXT` data type is:

```
LONGTEXT [BINARY] [CHARACTER SET charset_name] [COLLATE collation_name]
```

Therefore, try:

```
CREATE TABLE b (
  id int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  b_title VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
  b_data LONGTEXT CHARACTER SET utf8
);
```

Comment: so it is okay to use this kind a table for tynemce , I mean for big amount of data yes ? :)

Comment: @Tornike: I'm not familiar with tynemce, however `LONGTEXT` can store 4GB of text.